# No type arguments expected for class Flow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I encountered a problem with Kotlin Flow.

I copied the following code code from the Official guide

```
fun simple(): Flow<Int> = flow { 
    for (i in 1..3) {
        delay(100) 
        emit(i) 
    }
}
```

But the Android Studio prompts a following error:

> No type arguments expected for class Flow

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Make sure you use `import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow` not `java.util.concurrent.Flow`, it gives you this error because Java concurrent Flow class take 0 type arguments, but Coroutines Flow take one

Comment: you're right，thanks!

Comment: I also had to change the version of Kotlin coroutines from 1.6.0 to 1.5.2.

Comment: This has worked for me.